# How to pass a filed value result from one query to other query as input value under GET request in Grafana?

Tags: json, grafana

**Requirement:**

I am collecting Cluster details using JSON API with cluster ids (GET request is /rosa/clusters) which returns output like in attached screenshot.

[image]

Now I need to look feasibility to get node details of the respective clusters I got from 1st query by passing cluster id as argument in another query (GET request is /rosa{id)/nodes))
(refer the other screenshot).
[image]

Please note I can get he node count by passing manually each cluster id there as argument but I need to look to get nodes for all generated cluster ids using single GET request.

Is there any feasibility of using this method or someother methods like using data link would help on the same?

Looking forward to hear some interesting feedback and assistance.

I can get the cluster id data and can pass manually each cluster id to other query to get data but exception is how I can get for cluster ids generated from first query which can be passed to second query automatically to get the required nod details of all cluster at once.